# Laravel with AMAZON S3 Storage

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, storage

- I already changed the s3 driver in config/filesystem.php
- .env is already set up .

Error: Class "League\Flysystem\AwsS3V3\PortableVisibilityConverter" not found in file /Users/ADMIN/John/gaportalbe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemManager.php on line 240

Here's my controller function.

```
  public function s3test(Request $request){
          $file = $request->file('file');
          $path = Storage::disk('s3')->put('folder', $file, ['visibility' => 'public']);
   }
```

I was trying to solve it by composer update, changing all the composer.json with require filesystems ^3.8.0 and still not working.

Comment: did you `composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of composer update run the below

`composer require league/flysystem-sftp-v3 "^3.0"`

checkout https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#ftp-driver-configuration for further information.

If you have already got the above working, if you dd($path) see what is returned